# Is (or will there be) there a Blender-based GUI library, like GTK (based on GIMP)?

Tags: interface

Since Blender's GUI has so different approach to the whole area You see on the screen, I'm wondering about programming software that has a GUI based on that of Blender.

For many applications (where You have to keep an eye on many aspect at the same time) this would offer a much better approach than conventional GUI libraries.

Obviously there isn't such a project. Why?

Comment: I think there's no such thing, now, but since years Ton (blender creator and still current leader) wants a "simplified ui" version of blender targeted to children and/or less experienced users, codenamed "101": that could (arguably) mean that a "pluggable" interface engine is needed... if that happens, there could be a chance to get what you mean above, imho.

Comment: Quite interesting, since Blender's UI is quite unique and very flexible.